Pascal's wager and paganism
So it has been pointed out that Pascal's wager has the flaw that it can be used to support belief in Paganism.
Pascal apparently tries to prove you should go to Christianity due to the historical record of Christianity. Which leaves you with the question what is the point of the wager then if ultimately it relies on historical facts.
You can object that the wager prompts you to believe in the most likely of Gods and because one simple God is more likely than several then that is the God you must believe. The God of the philosopher is then is the Demiurge of Plato. An undivisible perfect point with perfect reason and perfect love and morality. We can question if perfect logic leads to perfect love or why this abstract God becomes less of an abstract entity and rather a complex character with moods and feelings and human concerns. A personal God,a big celestial bro. As it is reflected in the bible in many passages that were written before God was atributted more superpowers he was less of a perfect character and more of a flawed one.
But I think there is a deeper objection. What if the wager can be used to argue for an anti-God, not Satan, I mean a God that gets pissed off for doing some of what God demands.
So if God wants you to have faith in him, and accept Jesus as savior and pray, anti-God gets pissed off at you.
anti-God does not ask for anything else. As long as you never do those 3 things you get paradise, if you do you die. That is all he asks.
And so we see there are infinite pairs of Gods and anti-Gods. A God that sends you to heaven if you eat cheese, an anti-God(that is actually just another God) that sends you to heaven if you never eat cheese.
There are uncountable Gods with infinite possible demands and so instead of worrying about the chair-God that will send you to hell if you ever sit in a chair, better live your life.
What flaws do you see in this argument?

For Pascal at least "God" was a serious concept. In your version of the argument, the assumptions are all purely imaginary, so no one will even be tempted to take this seriously. Considered only as formal game-theoretic argument however, all those arguments are equivalent. If an anti-God is assumed to exist and if that's what the anti-God gives as rewards/punishments, then the argument has the same validity as Pascal's.

The strongest counter-argument against Pascal's argument is not that it's not formally valid - it's that it's profoundly a-religious and demonstrates an extremely crude level of moral sense (much cruder than Pascal's actual personal religiousity and ethical sense, I think) - the moral sense of a toddler who's ethics is still dominated by external reward/punishment. (I know certain people never grow out of this, but it's still pretty primitive.)

Also "belief" (or "faith" n a religious context) are not a matter of personal choice. Atheists and orthodox calvinists can agree on that :)

So is the question: can and does Pascal's Wager logically support implications that go against the intention of the argument?

Many-gods is indeed one criticism of Pascal's wager. I'd argue that common Christianity theology contains a bunch of things that are either outright contradiction or is required to be the exact opposite of what it seems like (which is where Christians commonly employ "God is beyond understanding"). So that far outweighs some fallacious appeal to popularity or dubious historical evidence, and any number of deities I can think up right now seems more likely. E.g. a god who made false religions to test if we have intellectual humility and actual concern for others (pass) or blind belief (fail).

This is a version of what is called "professor's god" who rewards agnostics and atheists and punishes theists. The problem is that such a god lacks initial plausibility upon which the wager is pragmatically conditioned, see Boaheng:"expecting a god who is kind to unbelievers and cruel to believers is
farfetched; no one has really believed in such a god. Since Pascal’s Wager is a pragmatic argument, it is a
mistake to invoke a bizarre god to refute his argument."

@Conifold From my perspective, the god of Christianity "lacks initial plausibility" and is one of the most "farfetched" and "bizarre" gods I can conceive of. Most people are just raised with the belief that the inconsistencies, implausibilities and contradictions within Christianity are all true, which makes it seem a whole lot more plausible (although what also feeds into that is how many children are raised, with the idea that they should just blindly listen to their parents, and that assaulting, abusing and tormenting them is a form of love, which is much like God's law and his "love").

@NotThatGuy Since the argument is merely pragmatic and people raised around such conceptions are Pascal's target audience, plausibility to them is the only one that matters. There is no point raising objections that are "bizarre" to those at whom the argument is directed. As for the more detached perspective, there is no point forcing the open door either. Pascal himself does not purport to rely on abstracted rationality, "the heart has reasons the reason knows nothing of." Those with unmoved hearts are free to dismiss it out of hand.

@Conifold "plausibility to [Pascal's target audience] is the only one that matters" - to some extent, yes. But biases are failings of rationality and I'm trying to evaluate Pascal's argument and Christianity independent of biases. My point is that Christianity shouldn't be as plausible as many think it is (those who might be sold on Pascal's wager). I consider there to be a single best way to evaluate data to get to what's most consistent with objective truth (even if this is an ideal). So I see it as a problem (generally) when an argument convinces some people but not others.

@mudskipper Did you ever actually read the relevant passage by Pascal? The reason why Pascal thinks Christianity is a good bet is because morality is desirable in itself. "Now, to what harm will you come by making this choice? You will be faithful, honest, humble, grateful, generous, a sincere friend, truthful. Certainly you will not enjoy these pernicious delights—glory and luxury; but will you not experience others?"

@but will you be more moral under christianity especially if the main featur that is asked of you is obedience and loyalty, to believe despite all evidence as an act of arrogance called faith.

@NotThatGuy
Yes I agree that it is a very bizarre God hence why I am not concerned with objections about whether or not chair God is ridiculous, because at least chair God is consistent and simple, chair God is much more plausible than the christian God with all tis complexities and quirks, he only seems more plausible to believers because he feels more human and believers find a sentient universe more plausible than the actual inhuman way the world is structured with no concern for human concerns. The universe if it had a God would be more like chair God due to its alien nature to intuiton

And hehnce why I find the argument about the heart having reasons that the reason does not know to be so implausible. Reason is the one that is mysterous to the heart not the other way around. We live in an alien world. One where the balance of equations with abstract quantities like Energy is important, and where human concerns like hierarchies or social power are meaningless or irrelevant.

To the OP, I would suggest reading the relevant passage from Pensées pages 64-69, (keeping in mind that Pascal thinks that history indicates the truth of Christianity given theistic ontological commitments) then asking for further clarification here if desired.

@gs - I did read Pascal - in French even :) -  but a long time ago, so the details have become a bit vague. I still stand behind my comments. Note also that I wrote that I did not think P. himself was that crude. My main point it that his argument, as presented is both formally valid and ridiculous.

This question is similar to: Does Pascal's wager contain any logical flaws or fallacies?. Also https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/43694 If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@tkruse - Indeed - Also https://religions.wiki/index.php/Pascal%27s_Wager#Counter-arguments gives an excellent (pretty nuanced) overview of all the flaws in Pascal's Wager (including the many-gods or anti-god counter-argument).

The wikipedia article on Pascals wager and the SEP article probably say all that has been said and all that needs to be said about Pascals wager.

So it has been pointed out that Pascal's wager has the flaw that it can be used to support belief in Paganism.

The term "Paganism" has various different uses, so it's best avoided or qualified to be precise. Here, the logic argument probably can include any and all other possible religions.

What if the wager can be used to argue for an anti-God, ...

Wikipedia calls this the "Argument from inconsistent revelations", and it was even known and used at the time Pascal lived.
But since Pascal's wager is not actually a proof of god or proof that it's best to believe, but rather a proof that it's foolish to try to use logic to justify faith, it does not really need a counter-argument of that sort.

This question reveals the absurdity at the heart of Pascal's Wager, and how easily it collapses under even the slightest scrutiny.
Pascal's Wager is not an argument for God, but for a god. It's a cynical calculation based on fear, not reason. Even if we accept its faulty premise—that belief is a choice—it offers no guidance on which god to choose. As the question rightly points out, why not a capricious god who punishes faith, or a pantheon of deities with conflicting demands?
The "simpler god" argument is nonsense. Complexity is not a mark against existence. The universe is demonstrably complex. To assume a "simple" god is more likely is pure anthropocentric bias, imagining a deity that fits our limited understanding.
The wager ignores the burden of proof. It's not on us to disprove an infinite number of ludicrous gods. It's on the believer to provide evidence for their specific deity. And let's be frank, the historical record of Christianity, with its contradictions, inconsistencies, and often barbaric acts committed in its name, hardly constitutes compelling evidence.
Addressing the "Anti-God" Scenario
This is a clever illustration of the wager's flaw. However, it's important to note:
The problem isn't multiple gods, but the lack of evidence for any. The wager tries to bypass the need for evidence by making a bet. But a bet on a horse race with no horses is meaningless.
This line of thinking leads to paralysis, not liberation. If we must fear an infinite number of unknowable gods, then any action, even inaction, becomes potentially damning. This is not a recipe for a meaningful life, but for a terrified existence.
Overall Pascal's Wager is intellectual cowardice. It's an attempt to justify belief without the hard work of critical thinking and honest examination of evidence. We have only one life. Let's not waste it on fear of imaginary beings, but live it with courage, reason, and compassion—without the need for celestial bribes or threats.

Pascal at this point is writing to a hypothetical reader who has already agreed that Christianity is desirable and plausible but is not convinced that it is true. There are uncountable multitudes of out-of-context paraphrasings either overstating Pascal's point or straw-manning it for hostile analysis, which pretty much all leave this out.
If bastardized into an argument and not a meditation in a book of meditations, the wager as actually put by Pascal would run:
Premises:

The wager is necessary: you cannot conclude, you must bet, and you must bet blindly. In modern terms, the two sides of the wager are a priori ontological commitments, not possible conclusions, even stochastic conclusions, from any body of evidence.

If God, hence miracles, are real, history implies Christianity. (Not stated in the relevant passage, but clearly implied elsewhere in Pensees.)

Christianity is desirable of itself for bringing virtue and resolving angst, independent of its truth value. (Partially described in the relevant passage, but more fully elaborated elsewhere in Pensees.)

If Christianity is true, heaven is promised to those who believe and obey.


Therefore game theoretically:

Believe and Christianity true: win big.
Believe and Christianity false: win.
Not-believe Christianity true: lose big.
Not-believe and Christianity false: lose.

Therefore the winning move is to bet on Believe and Obey.
Constructing a straw-man of Pascal by omitting 2 and 4, or presenting the consequences of Christian belief as a malus in this life and thus changing to:

Win big
Lose small
Lose big
Win small

...or by omitting or distorting one the other premises, does make the wager vulnerable to arguments that it is a flase dilemma, or that 1 and 3 have sufficiently low probability to bet on not-Believe, or that it is a morally crude transactional approach antithetical to the teaching of Christ.
It surely doesn't help that most of the straw Pascals are presented by Christian apologists supporting (and overstating or mis-representing) Pascal's conclusion, and many of the rest appear in respectable looking philosophy textbooks and encyclopedia articles.
There's also nothing novel about the version usually presented. You can find proto-game-theory exhortations from preachers in every century who never heard about Pascal.
By all means, skewer the false dilemmas for what they are. But if you want to argue against Pascal, engage one of his premises.
Note that disputing a premise does not automatically dispute the conclusion: the premise may have been extraneous, the conclusion may be true but unsubstantiated (requiring other premuses not stated), or the conclusion may be false and unsubstantiated.

But I still disagree with this "stronger argument", 2 and 4 are just not true. Plenty or christians are immoral and/or unhappy because of religion not in spite of. An example: The endless anxiety of being damned drives modern foreign policy in the Middle East. Another one: The Protestast Work Ethic that Weber spoke of and how it glorifies prossperity(read money) as a signifier of salvation.
I also don't understand this point: If God, hence miracles, are real, history implies Christianity"

I mean if God is real God implies Christianity no need for the historical record, also if God is real the historical record doesn't matter. If the historical record helps increase the probability of God then this could work, but the historical record shows the incredible mess that was early Christianity with hundred of edits to the gospels and competing sects. Ask any bible scholar if Exodus is based on historical facts, let alone undistorted hsitorical facts. Moses is not believed to be real by modern scholars


Pascal apparently tries to prove you should go to Christianity...

Actually Pascal was communicating with Christians.  The Wager was an argument for them to stay in Christianity and was not an attempt to convince non-Christians to enter it.

Thus the discussion of wagering in favour of religious belief in the
Pensées (Fragment 397: II, 676–81), which Pascal drafted and revised a
number of times, was written from the perspective of someone who
already believed in God, and who assumed that their belief was itself
a gift from God. Pascal had independently studied the mathematics of
gambling, and while considering how to compose an apology or defence
of Christianity, he reviewed ways in which a committed Christian > >
might
adapt the logic of wagering to show that their belief is not
unreasonable. However, according to Pascal’s deepest theological
convictions, nothing that he wrote in this context could persuade an
unbeliever to become a believer in any sense that could lead to
salvation. No one can communicate religious faith in Pascal’s sense to
others by reasoning or wagering, nor can such faith be self-induced by
the same methods. For Pascal, a decision to believe God’s revelation
(in the relevant sense of ‘believe’) is not based on rational
calculation nor, as indicated above, does it presuppose a
philosophical argument in favour of God’s existence. A calculation of
the probability of one’s wager is logically posterior to belief, and
it purports to show only that those who have accepted divine grace and
believed in God have made a wager that is not unreasonable. Why?
Because the significance or value of the belief as a means to eternal
salvation would, if it were true, compensate for its relative
implausibility.
-Stanford’s Encyclopedia of Philosophy

So, it could, perhaps be transferred to believers in other dieties, whether one or many, but that wouldn't be Pascal's Wager. Especially if it was used to convince someone to take on a belief system - for example, to get someone to become pagan when they are not already.
It wasn't aimed at those in a neutral or non-belief postion.

First Pest to Post: you asked what are the flaws in your argument (paraphrased) that: it is better to live your life than be concerned about gods, plausible or otherwise. As for most things, it depends where you are standing, or perhaps when.
One part of the Philosophical mindset is the principle of charity: interpreting an assertion in a reasonably favorable way. I am not saying that you are uncharitable or have said anything wrong. But I think the answer to your question is not really with present day logic and viewpoints.
Charity (which actually means 'love') is to consider the benighted state of humanity at large up to and including the present. That people have had very little truth to go on in a harsh world with injury, illness and death coming upon them seemingly at random. People in general do not crave reasons so much as reassurance. It is very hard to survive at all with no hope, let alone being also caring towards others. Reflect occasionally on the vast amount of ignorance and suffering that humanity has lived through, and which a majority still face.
We could imagine that coming up with the idea of God is a fail-safe mechanism in the psyche for beings able to ask such questions. Before we could have better knowledge, we had to live long enough to acquire it. And morals, however ascribed, are a win for society. There is time to improve them after they are in place.
I have many times throughout my life asked similar questions about the mental abilities of people, but it is important to realize that even being able to frame such doubts is a sign of unusal 'privilege', and so it requires unusal charity to be extended.

I guess that would be true if religion consistently allowed people to be better people, instead of the horrible mixed results that we get

@LinaJane Douglas Hofstadter came up with the idea of "renormalized rationality". What I am saying is something like "reimagined humanity". 'Philosophy' comes from the root words 'love of wisdom', be sure to keep the Love foremost, or there is no point entertaining it at all.

"And morals, however ascribed, are a win for society. There is time to improve them after they are in place" It's a cultist myth that humanity owes any morality to religions. Humanity behaved according to good moral standards well before people believed in gods. And most religions like Christianity provide deeply flawed morality full of racism, sexism, homophobia, violence and hate. Hope is also possible without religion, even though churches try to teach people that they are weak, to strengthen the monopoly of priests on hope. The more easier for same priests prey on choir boys then.

@ScottRowe - In terms of wisdom - Has the history of Western philosophy since roughly Descartes exhibited much wisdom in your eyes? Or has philosophy mostly dabbled in useless abstract frivolities and dark existential nonsense poetry (which is how I charitably read both Pascal and his modern atheist/manicheist alterego Emil Cioran) which overall contributed to (more than prevented or has given us tools to work against) the crisis of alienation and the world-wide ecological crisis?

@mudskipper the principles of good will apply no matter how many people have done badly for however long.

@tkruse the great thing about making improvements is that the sources of the material don't matter. If a bad person hands you a glass of water, it's still water to you.

@ScottRowe - Totally agree. But morality and moralism are often counter-productive. "The highest virtue is not virtuous, that's why it has virtue." (Laozi, 38) But what you say seems to harmonize with "Good people are not contentious; contentious people are not good" (Laozi, 81, LeGuin translation) :)

@mudskipper people do tend to get the means and the end mixed up.
